# DocumentContext not returning value

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, lotusscript

I am using following code in a Java Agent in Lotus Notes:

```
Session session = getSession();
AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
Document doc = agentContext.getDocumentContext();
```

But it is returning docvariable as `Null` value. I am initialting agent in `LotusScript` code in postsave of the form. When I am using it in postsave by ToolsRun MAcro it is running fine. But initiating it by Run method of Lotus Script is not working at all.

can anyone help me to know what could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run an agent using the Run method, you can pass a NoteId and access it in the agent with the ParameterDocId property.

I don't have a good explanation for the reason it is this way, however, the DocumentContext property does behave differently depending on the context in which the agent is running.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [documentation for DocumentContext](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DOCUMENTCONTEXT_PROPERTY_JAVA.html). You can determine what is happening by process of elimination. You are not running from a view, before new mail arrives or from a browser. This means that DocumentContext is not established for your agent.

You could do something like this in the PostSave event:

```
Sub Postsave(Source As Notesuidocument)
    Dim ns As New NotesSession, agent As NotesAgent
    Set agent=ns.CurrentDatabase.GetAgent("PostSave Agent")
    Call agent.Run(Source.Document.NoteID)
End Sub
```

Then do this in your agent to get the passed document:

```
Database db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();
Agent agent = agentContext.getCurrentAgent();
Document doc = db.getDocumentByID(agent.getParameterDocID());
```

Comment: Thanks. But what i finally did was, change the code to call agent in Formula language and it worked.. Dont know why.. but it certainly did.

Comment: i was using that in an agent. The agent i was calling was from postsave.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below steps need to be done...

1. Check the Agent should be sign with Server ID or Administrator ID
2. Need to check the Run as Web user(Property) in Agent property.
3. Check your Agent Target - View Window or None